# Why Does a B+ tree could be more ineficent than a B tree in random search?

Tags: database, data-structures, tree, theory

I was wondering why a B+ tree could be more ineficent than a B tree in a random search (I read this in a theory book but doesn't explain why) considering that the only difference at least I know that exist between this two types of data structures, is that B+ trees got in every leave node a pointer to the next node I think there is something that I am mising, could someone explain me another difference between this two data structures?

Comment: I Know the answer, it is because a B+ tree has all their elements in a leave node, so every search need to read H times, being H the Height of the tree. That's not needed in a B tree, because in this kind of tree an element can be stored in the "middle" of the tree, so you don't need to read till the end of the structure to know if a n element exist or not.

Comment: But there aren't any early exits when you might have found a match in an internal node